# Can't get body node from html document using xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I know this is a stupid question but i just cant find an issue with it. Can't get inner text from body node in html document using `xpath`.

**Code i am using:**

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(String.Format(url, companyName));

HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
string code = null;
try
{
     code = node.FirstChild.InnerText;
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
}
```

**website structure**:

```html
<html>
     <body>PYRIX | preston york</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `node.InnerText` should do it.

Comment: nah. it wont because any node that has text in it is actually inside the text node within the element. So, firstChild here would we textnode

Comment: `string text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerText;` for me this works...

Answer (score 0):

I just tried `node.InnerText` and it works. The problem must be in how you are loading the document.

This works:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<html><body>PYRIX | preston york</body></html>");

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```